# How to debug "Can't downgrade database from 3 to 4" SQLite error in Android?

Tags: android, sqlite

When I use Sqlite in Android, file logcat in Eclipse display message is:

> Can't downgrade database from 3 to 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

possible reason for the exceptions are :

- The device that you're running the code on has a database file of version 2.
- *onDowngrade()* is not overridden in your code.
- The code is requesting version 1 of the database (with a param to SQLiteOpenHelper constructor)